# How to copy variable address in Visual Studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, copy, memory-address

In the *watching* window I can add `&` before a variable to see its address, but how to copy it's address?

I can create a new pointer to this variable in order to copy the pointer's value (the var's address) in watching window.
But how to copy the address directly?

Comment: add an expression `pointer = &variable`?

Comment: it's not convinience

Comment: why do you need the address in value?

Comment: I need to watch the variable in memory, I can only type address in search bar in memory sheet

Comment: No need to type, just [drag the address into memory window](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s3aw423e.aspx)

Comment: it works, can you post your comment as an answer that I can accept it ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to drag and drop the address into the memory window

> ## Selecting a Memory Location
>
> If you want to move instantly to a selected location in memory, you can do so by using a drag-and-drop operation or by editing the value in the **Address** box. The **Address** box accepts not only numeric values but also expressions that evaluate to addresses. By default, the **Memory** window treats an **Address** expression as a live expression, which is reevaluated as your program executes. Live expressions can be very useful. For example, you can use them to view the memory that is touched by a pointer.
>
> ### To select a memory location by dragging and dropping
>
> - In any window, select a memory address or pointer variable that contains a memory address.
> - Drag the address or pointer to the **Memory** window.

[MSDN - Memory Windows - select a memory location](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/memory-windows?view=vs-2015)